# ActiveRecord: Update foreign key in patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Tables:

```
apps:
ID (PK)
name
status_id (FK to status table)

status:
ID(PK)
name


class App < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :status
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps
end
```

I have a few statuses.

```
Name       PK
Unreviewed (1)
Reviewed   (2)
Beta       (3)
```

I want to change the status of all apps that have a status of 'Beta' to a status of 'Unreviewed'.  The primary key is what is stored in the Apps table.  However I don't want to just key of the PK as it may not be exactly the same in all DBs.  I want to key off of the status name for the update.

I cannot seem to figure out how to issue an update_all on the Apps table.

Tried this, but it is not working
    App.update_all(:status => 'Tested', :status => 'Beta')

Comment: can you post how your models look like, what are the attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `App.update_all("appstatus = 'Tested'", "appstatus = 'Beta'")`. The first part of the `update_all` is what you're setting, the second is the condition. I don't think using hash rockets with `update_all` works to set the values and conditions the way you have it.

**Based on the updated question text:**

```
App.includes(:status).where("statuses.name = ?", 'Beta').update_all(["apps.status_id = ?", Status.find_by_name('Tested')])
```

you could also do something:

```
testing_status = Status.find_by_name('Testing')
App.update_all(['status_id = ?', testing_status.id], 'status_id = 3')
```

Based on what you're trying to do, I'd really suggest just making the status as a string on the App model. It'll make you're life a lot easier.

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base

  STATUSES = {:testing => 'Testing', :unreviewed => 'Unreviewed', :reviewed => 'Reviewed', :beta => 'Beta']

  # then you can create scopes to help you
  STATUSES.each do |status_type, status_value|
    scope status_type, lambda { where(:status => status_value) }
  end
end
```

Then when you want to do a bulk update:

```
App.beta.update_all("status = ?", App::STATUSES[:testing])
```

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "appstatus" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "apps" SET appstatus = 'Tested' WHERE (appstatus = 'B...   I think because appstatus does not really exist in the DB, thats ActiveRecords relationship name.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work (since I have nothing to test with at the moment), but `App.includes(:status).where("statuses.name = ?", 'Beta').update_all(["apps.status_id = ?", Status.find_by_name('Tested')])`

Comment: App.includes(:status).where("statuses.name = ?", 'Beta').update_all(["apps.status_id = ?", Status.find_by_name('Tested')]) still does not work.  what is 'statuses.name'?

Comment: It's the name of table for the `Status` model o_O. It's the rails convention, for example: a model with the name `Post` has a table in the database named `posts`, so when you do queries you can reference the table name like `Post.where('posts.id = 1')`

Comment: Got this to work, probably a much better way but this is ok for now.       App.where(:appstatus_id => Appstatus.select('id').where(:name => 'Beta')).update_all(:appstatus_id=>Appstatus.select('id').where(:name=>'Tested').first)